# Is there some more general conclusion?

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear algebra there's something similar between dual map and adjoint.

Here is what I draw for dual map:
[image]

, and this is for adjoint:
[image]

Though in dual map case there are 2 things on each side ($V$ and $V'$ on left, and $W$ and $W'$ on right), while adjoint has only 1 on each side ($V$ on left and $W$ on right), still the shapes have some similarity.

Is there something more general for such kind of relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Hilbert space (inner product space with a complete topology - any finite-dimensional inner product space is automatically Hilbert), the dual space of *continuous* functionals (for finite dimensions, this is all functionals) is isomorphic to the original space:

For each $v \in V$, we can define the functional $\phi_v \in V'$ by $w \overset{\phi_v}\mapsto \langle v, w\rangle$. Then the map $$\Phi_V : V \to V' : v \mapsto \phi_v$$ is an isomorphism.

For a linear map $T : V \to W$ between Hilbert spaces, the dual and adjoint maps are related by $$T' = \Phi_V \circ T^* \circ \Phi_W^{-1}$$

Effectively $T'$ and $T^*$ are the same map, where the isomorphisms $\Phi_V, \Phi_W$ are used to identify $V'$ with $V$ and $W'$ with $W$.